# ¿Como puedo evitar que el metodo del services retorne null usando mockito?

Tags: jpa, java-8, mockito, junit-5

Estoy realizando un test para la capa Service pero cuando realizo la invocacion al metodo que se esta testeando este arroja un error controlado de null, el null se produce porque en el test se inserta el objeto pero el metodo del repositorio devuelve un null.
¿Saben como puedo hacer que el metodo no retorne un null?

Este es mi test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CompetenciaServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CompetenciaServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    private CompetenciasRepository competenciasRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void crear() throws Exception {

        CompetenciaEntity competenciaEntity = CompetenciaDataTest.getCompetenciaEntity();
        when(competenciasRepository.save(competenciaEntity)).thenReturn(competenciaEntity);

        CompetenciaDTO competenciaDTO = CompetenciaDataTest.getCompetenciaDTO();

        CompetenciaDTO outputDTO = service.crear(competenciaDTO);

        assertEquals(competenciaDTO.getId(), outputDTO.getId());
        assertEquals(competenciaDTO.getNombre(), outputDTO.getNombre());
        assertEquals(competenciaDTO.getCategorias().size(), outputDTO.getCategorias().size());


        verify(competenciasRepository, times(1)).save(any(CompetenciaEntity.class));
    }
}
```

Esta es la implementacion

```
@Override
    public CompetenciaDTO crear(CompetenciaDTO inputDTO) throws Exception {
        CompetenciaEntity competenciaEntity = Builder.competencia().buildEntity(inputDTO);
        competenciaEntity = competenciasRepository.save(competenciaEntity);// este método retorna null

        return Builder.competencia().buildDTO(competenciaEntity);
    }
```

genere un componente builder para pasar de entidad a dto y viceversa

```
@Component
public class CompetenciaBuilder {

    private CategoriaBuilder categoriaBuilder;
    private UserBuilder userBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public CompetenciaBuilder(CategoriaBuilder categoriaBuilder, UserBuilder userBuilder) {
        this.categoriaBuilder = categoriaBuilder;
        this.userBuilder = userBuilder;
    }


    public CompetenciaDTO buildDTO(CompetenciaEntity entity) throws Exception {
        CompetenciaDTO dto = new CompetenciaDTO();

        try {
            if (entity == null)//entra en este if ya que entity esta como null
                throw new Exception("No se puede construir DTO de una entidad vacia");

            dto.setId(entity.getId());
            dto.setNombre(entity.getNombre());
            dto.setHabilitada(EnumEstados.fromValue(entity.getHabilitada()));
            dto.setCreatedAt(entity.getCreatedAt());
            dto.setUpdatedAt(entity.getUpdatedAt());

            dto.setOrganizador(userBuilder.buildDTO(entity.getOrganizador()));
            dto.setCategorias(categoriaBuilder.buildListDTO(entity.getCategorias()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        return dto;
    }

    public CompetenciaEntity buildEntity(CompetenciaDTO dto) throws Exception {
        if (dto == null)
            throw new NullPointerException(Constantes.NO_SE_PUEDE_CONSTRUIR_ENTIDAD_EN_COMPETENCIA_BUILDER);

        CompetenciaEntity entity = new CompetenciaEntity();
        entity.setNombre(dto.getNombre());
        entity.setHabilitada(dto.getHabilitada().value());
        entity.setCreatedAt(dto.getCreatedAt());
        entity.setUpdatedAt(dto.getUpdatedAt());

        UsersEntity user = userBuilder.buildEntity(dto.getOrganizador());
        entity.setOrganizador(user);

        Set<CategoriaEntity> categoriasEntity = categoriaBuilder.buildSetEntity(dto.getCategorias());
        entity.setCategorias(categoriasEntity);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Este es el repository

```
public interface CompetenciasRepository extends CrudRepository<CompetenciaEntity,Long> {

}
```

Esta es la respuesta de la consola, si alguien vio algo que a mi se me paso se los agradeceria un monton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]